# how to use LabelEncoder and Random Forest in Pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to use `Pipeline` from `scikit-learn`. At present I am doing following:

1. Apply `LabelEncoder` on some features
2. Build a `RandomForest` Regressor

The code is:

```
x['zipcode'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(x['zipcode'])

rfr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=20, random_state=0)

rfr.fit(x, y)
```

How do I build a `Pipeline` so that the future unseen data goes through same transformation?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to put your LabelEncoder transformation inside a sklearn `Pipeline` instruction. So, the possible solution to do this will be to call for LabelEncoder ,for example like follows:

```
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

lbl = LabelEncoder()
lbl.fit(X)
np.save('lbl_encoder.npy', encoder.classes_)
```

and load it when needed

```
lbl = LabelEncoder
lbl.classes_ = np.load('lbl_encoder.npy')
```

Comment: thanks. However, I am planing to deploy the final model and with Pipeline, you can save the model as `pkl` file which will include all the transformers as well.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, I would create my own `PipeLine`.
Please consider this simple example, you can customize it and add to it in accordance to your requirements:

```
import copy
import pickle
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class MyPipeline:
    def __init__(self, column='zipcode', n_estimators=10, random_state=0):
        # add any parameters as required
        # customize as required
        assert isinstance(column, str)
        self.column = column
        self.label_enc = LabelEncoder()
        self.model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=n_estimators,
                                           random_state=random_state,
                                           n_jobs=1)

    def preprocess(self, x):
        processed_x = copy.deepcopy(x)
        processed_x[self.column] = self.label_enc.fit_transform(processed_x[self.column])
        return np.array(processed_x)

    def fit(self, x, y):
        # also customize as required
        transformed_x = self.preprocess(x)
        print("X After Transform: \n{}\n".format(transformed_x))
        self.model.fit(transformed_x, y)

    def predict(self, unseen_x):
        # also customize as required
        processed_x = copy.deepcopy(unseen_x)
        processed_x[self.column] = self.label_enc.transform(processed_x[self.column])
        print("Unseen Data After Transform: \n{}\n".format(np.array(processed_x)))
        return self.model.predict(np.array(processed_x))
```

---

### Test

```
x = pd.DataFrame(columns=['blabla','zipcode'],
                 data=[[1, 'zipecode1'], [2,'zipecode2'], [3,'zipecode3'],
                       [4, 'zipecode4'], [5, 'zipecode5'], [6, 'zipecode6'],
                       [7, 'zipecode7'], [8, 'zipecode8'], [9, 'zipecode9']])
y = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]

mypipeline = MyPipeline()
mypipeline.fit(x,y)

# save it for future work
with open('mypipeline.dat', 'wb') as pickle_file:
    pickle.dump(mypipeline, pickle_file)

# retrieve it
with open('mypipeline.dat', 'rb') as pickle_file:
    mypipeline_ = pickle.load(pickle_file)

# Here I am passing same x just to make sure it's doing proper transformation
result = mypipeline_.predict(x)

# the result
print("Results: {}".format(result))
```

### Output

```
X After Transform: 
[[1 0]
 [2 1]
 [3 2]
 [4 3]
 [5 4]
 [6 5]
 [7 6]
 [8 7]
 [9 8]]

Unseen Data After Transform: 
[[1 0]
 [2 1]
 [3 2]
 [4 3]
 [5 4]
 [6 5]
 [7 6]
 [8 7]
 [9 8]]

Results: [12. 18. 28. 37. 47. 56. 69. 79. 82.]
```